# Laravel infinite notifications loop

Tags: php, laravel, apache, queue

I'm trying to send a notification using a custom channel, and gets triggered inside an `updated` event:

`$model->notifyNow(new LatiniaNotification($body));`

Everything was working just fine, and the notifications were queued until I replaced the `notify` method with `notifyNow`... now I'm receiving an inifinite amount of notifications, and I can't figure out why (now both methods triggers the loop).

The method `shouldSend` is also being ignored...

Any clues?

Channel:

```
...
    /**
     * Send the given notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @param  Notification  $notification
     * @return void
     */
    public function send($notifiable, Notification $notification)
    {
        $array = method_exists($notification, 'toLatinia')
            ? $notification->toLatinia($notifiable)
            : $notification->toArray($notifiable);

        if (empty($array)) {
            return;
        }

        if(Latinia::send($array) && method_exists($notification, 'markAsSent')) {
            $notification->markAsSent($notifiable);
        }
    }
...
```

Notification:

(I removed the ShouldQueue contract and still the same)

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications\Notifications\Latinia;

use App\Support\AFR\API\Latinia\NotificationBody;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Config\Repository;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class Latinia extends Notification
{

    /**
     * Notification's body.
     *
     * @var []
     */
    protected $body = [];

    /**
     * Update model field on notification sent.
     *
     * @var string|null
     */
    protected $sentField = null;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @param $body
     * @param $sentField
     */
    public function __construct($body = null, $sentField = null)
    {
        // Override defaults
        if($body instanceof NotificationBody) {
            $body->from($this->from());
            $this->body = $body;
        }

        if(is_string($sentField)) {
            $this->sentField($sentField);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return string[]
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['latinia'];
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the notification should be sent.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @param  string  $channel
     * @return bool
     */
    public function shouldSend($notifiable, $channel)
    {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Default sender.
     *
     * @return Repository|Application|mixed
     */
    protected function from()
    {
        return config('AFR.notifications.api.from_mail');
    }

    /**
     * Model's sent field to update.
     *
     * @param $field
     * @return $this
     */
    public function sentField($field) {
        $this->sentField = $field;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Update field on sent notification if sentField is defined.
     *
     * @param $notifiable
     * @return void
     */
    public function markAsSent($notifiable)
    {
        if(!is_null($this->sentField)) {
            $notifiable->update([
                "{$this->sentField}" => true
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     * (Keep the order: template, to, subject, data)
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray()
    {
        return $this->body ? $this->body->toArray() : [];
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     * (Keep the order: template, to, subject, data)
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function toLatinia()
    {
        return $this->body ? $this->body->toArray() : [];
    }

}
```

Note:
I'm using TNTSearch and the field updates for the index are being queued, I don't know if that has something to do with.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out...

When I sent the notification, I update the model (cc_mail_sent field) and that triggers the listener over and over recursively.